# Failed to mount component on Vue-cli 2 using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have used Webpack, Babel, Vue, and TypeScript to test a new project.
Everything was good when testing Webpack+Babel and Webpack+Babel+Vue for writing some Web apps with Vue files.

However, when translating the same code to TypeScript *(Webpack+Vue+TypeScript)*, something was wrong. Coding with Vue and TypeScript on .html and .ts files was fine, but only got wrong on loading .vue files.

*The picture shows the error on browser. 
And it did show the vue data on console with "Hello Vue TypeScript"*

[image]

Did I miss some setting of webpack, tsconfig, or something wrong? 
Please give me some hints to solve it.

**.html**

```
  <div id="app">
      <h1> Hello World TS</h1>
      <h3>{{message}}</h3>
      <hello></hello>
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from './components/HelloTs.vue'

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      message: "Hello Vue TypeScript"
  },
  components:{ 'hello': Hello }
})
console.log("vue $data: "+app.message)
```

**.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="message">
    Hi Vue
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class HelloComponent extends Vue {

}

</script>

<style scoped>
  .message {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types",
            "./node_modules/vue/types"
        ],
        "pretty": true
    }

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
   rules: [
    // TypeScript
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
         use: 'ts-loader',
         exclude: /node_modules/
       },
            // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
       // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [           
              'css-loader',
              'style-loader'
         ]
       },
       // this will apply to both plain `.vue` files
       {
         test: /\.vue$/,
         use: [
                'vue-loader',
                'vue-style-loader',
                'vue-template-compiler'
         ]
       }
    ]
},

plugins: [
        // make sure to include the plugin for vue-loader 15.*
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new CheckerPlugin()
],

// how modules are resolved.
resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx','.vue' ],
        alias:{
            vue$: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this error:

Method to import Vue component in **.ts** is as below,

```
components:{ 'hello' : HelloTs }
```

OR

You can give a name to the component to while exporting it as below,

```
export default class HelloComponent extends Vue {
   name : 'hello'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but it dosen't work. Is versions of webpack, ts-loader, typescript, or other tools I installed a possible issue of it? These are tools I installed below: 
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "vue": "2.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "12.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.2",
    "webpack": "2.5.0",
   "vue-class-component": "6.0.0",
    "vue-class-decorator": "7.6.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "6.0.0",

Comment: This is issue because component is not mounted properly. Can you please make the fiddle for the same? It will make easier to detect the issue.

Comment: You can also try to follow this method from official docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html